# Greeter variables are all undefined and contract doesn't run

Tags: go-ethereum, contract-deployment, greeter

I'm attempting to run the greeter contract on the live network. I'm following the commands as per the [official tutorial](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Contract-Tutorial), which worked on a test network when I tried it a while ago (on a different machine).

On entering the commands I'm getting an `undefined` response, though all variables are correctly defined when manually called on the console.

On entering the final `var greeter`, I'm correctly prompted for the passphrase of the account being used, which seems to go through. However, the pasted script itself doesn't seem to be called - there's no console log output.

Any ideas what I've missed out?

[Note: There's plenty of ether in the account being used.]

[Note2: The console has truncated long lines in the below log. I've confirmed they copied correctly.]

```
> {g) public { greeting = _greeting; } function greet() constant returns (string) { return greeting; } }'
undefined
> 
> var greeterCompiled = web3.eth.compile.solidity(greeterSource)
undefined
> var _greeting = "Reason has always existed, but not always in a reasonable form."
undefined
> var greeterContract = web3.eth.contract(greeterCompiled.greeter.info.abiDefinition);
undefined
> {,{from:web3.eth.accounts[0], data: greeterCompiled.greeter.code, gas: 1000000}, function(e, contract){
         if(!e) {

               if(!contract.address) {
               {saction send: TransactionHash: " + contract.transactionHash + " waiting to be mined  .");

                   } else {
                     console.log("Contract mined! Address: " + contract.address);
                     console.log(contract);
                   }

             }
       })
Please unlock account <account_address_removed>.
Passphrase: 
Account is now unlocked for this session.
undefined
```

Comment: Are you sure that geth is synced?

Comment: Yes - I've got the logs ticking away in an attached window.

Comment: did you try `web3.eth.defaultAccount = web3.eth.accounts[0]` ?

Comment: By the way it is your actually code ? are you trying to run the contract for the first time ? cause it looks incorrect if you do

var greeter = greeterContract.new(_greeting,{from:web3.eth.accounts[0], data: greeterCompiled.greeter.code, gas: 300000}, function(e, contract){
    if(!e) {

      if(!contract.address) {
        console.log("Contract transaction send: TransactionHash: " + contract.transactionHash + " waiting to be mined...");

      } else {
        console.log("Contract mined! Address: " + contract.address);
        console.log(contract);
      }

    }
})

Comment: I've tried setting `web3.eth.defaultAccount` as you suggested, but that hasn't helped. It's not my code - it's the standard Greeter code from the tutorial on the wiki: https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Contract-Tutorial. Which bit looks incorrect?

Comment: Hmm, the gas amount on the wiki is different to the amount on the homepage Greeter tutorial: https://ethereum.org/greeter

Comment: I have also attempted Greeter recently, but immediately started worrying at the first 'undefined'. My very strong impression is that the tutorial is significantly outdated - I think I saw on github the last update was 6+ months ago...

Comment: `undefined` in javascript isn't a bad thing. Variable declarations always return undefined, its nothing to worry about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer to [Deploying the Greeter contract via the geth CLI is not registering in my private blockchain](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2751/deploying-the-greeter-contract-via-the-geth-cli-is-not-registering-in-my-private) for a step-by-step guide for running the greeter example in your local dev blockchain.

The commands and the expected outputs in the Window #2 sections in the link above should be very similar in the live network.

And the `undefined` messages are expected and does not signal an error condition as stated in the comments by `Tjaden Hess` above.

You should see the `Contract transaction send` message with a transaction hash

```
var greeter = greeterContract.new(_greeting,{from: eth.accounts[0], data: greeterCompiled.greeter.code, gas: 4000000}, function(e, contract){   if(!e) {      if(!contract.address) {       console.log("Contract transaction send: TransactionHash: " + contract.transactionHash + " waiting to be mined...");      } else {       console.log("Contract mined! Address: " + contract.address);       console.log(contract);     }    } })
Contract transaction send: TransactionHash: 0x90d201388971770036898a7a22ab252cb0bf3c556f988a7b87583315cdaf58bc waiting to be mined...
undefined
```

If you don't see the following `Contract mined!` message, you may have to increase the gas value in your transaction sending message:

```
Contract mined! Address: 0x083628160c1cf218d14f2f0998c7a8dc72aec180
[object Object]
```