# Solidity compile contract return undefined

Tags: go-ethereum, solidity

I have a question when I use solidity to compile a simple contract. It like that:

```
> web3.eth.getCompilers()
["Solidity"]
> source = "contract test { function multiply(uint a) returns(uint d) { return a * 7; } }"
"contract test { function multiply(uint a) returns(uint d) { return a * 7; } }"
> source
"contract test { function multiply(uint a) returns(uint d) { return a * 7; } }"
> clientContract = eth.compile.solidity(source).test
undefined
```

I don't know why the result is "undefined", what is wrong? I'm using it on the mac os and also have the same question in ubuntu.

Comment: What happens if you just go > clientContract like you did with source?

Comment: > clientContract = eth.compile.solidity("contract test { function multiply(uint a) returns(uint d) { return a * 7; } }").test
undefined
>
Do you mean that ?

Comment: It's a _feature_ of the JavaScript console, it always teaches you about the return value. If there isn't anything to return, it displays _undefined_. That does not mean your function was not successfully executed.

Comment: Thanks. You are right. I did not understand well about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [Greeter variables are all undefined and contract doesn't run](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1293/greeter-variables-are-all-undefined-and-contract-doesnt-run) undefined in javascript isn't a bad thing. **Variable declarations always return undefined**, its nothing to worry about.

This commands worked for me. Check it out:

```
var source = "contract test { function multiply(uint a) returns(uint d) { return a * 7; } }";
var compiled = web3.eth.compile.solidity(source);
console.log(JSON.stringify(compiled));
```

Comment: But I saw some information on the network it show me that return will not be 'undefined'. And it will compile the contract and return something about the result.

Comment: Check the commands I added to the answer. Now it seems it compiles the code.

Comment: I can't get the code from the contract. I think my system environment also be wrong. But I can't find what's wrong with me.

Comment: I solve it, very thanks to your answer. The new version solidity v0.4.9 can't use ".test". The correct command is ''contract = web3.eth.compile.solidity(source)["<stdin>:test”]".